# Seeking open source point cloud software?

Tags: lidar, software-recommendations, point-cloud

Just acquired a [Geoslam](http://www.geoslam.com) Zeb-Revo for scanning our stockpiles and wondered if there was another option to process point cloud data?

Comment: (processing) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31472/working-with-lidar-data-using-other-than-esri-software; (visualization) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77427/viewing-lidar-data-from-web-browser; (python) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88322/what-lidar-processing-tools-are-available-in-python; (full wave form)  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33016/processing-full-waveform-lidar

Answer (score 1):

Best is a word relative to each person's head. The best is try the softwares .

Have a look at Cloud compare for example : http://www.danielgm.net/cc/
A collegue of mine tried it and says it's not bad.

> CloudCompare is a 3D point cloud (and triangular mesh) processing
>   software. It has been originally designed to perform comparison
>   between two dense 3D points clouds (such as the ones acquired with a
>   laser scanner) or between a point cloud and a triangular mesh. It
>   relies on a specific octree structure dedicated to this task. 
>   Afterwards, it has been extended to a more generic point cloud
>   processing software, including many advanced algorithms (registration,
>   resampling, color/normal/scalar fields handling, statistics
>   computation, sensor management, interactive or automatic segmentation,
>   display enhancement, etc.).